# How to convert a GPU (gpuR) matrix to a standard R matrix?

Tags: r, matrix, gpu

I have been using the package 'gpuR' to increase speed of code manipulating matrices.  A matrix (formed by as.matrix(x)) can be converted to a vclMatrix using the code below (vcl indicates the data is stored on the GPU)

```
vclm <- vcLMatrix(x)

multmatrix <- vclm * vclm
```

is much quicker than

```
multmatrix <- x * x
```

for a large matrix, but how do I convert the multmatrix back into a standard R matrix for further manipulation?

Also, any idea why multiplication is so much faster but element wise addition e.g.

```
addmatrix <- vclm + vclm
```

is significantly slower than adding standard matrices?

Many thanks, Antony

Comment: I recommend you reading the author's blog in [here](http://www.parallelr.com/r-gpu-programming-for-all-with-gpur/). Maybe helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is quite simple.  You can convert a `vclMatrix` or `gpuMatrix` to a `matrix` by simply passing square brackets.

```
r_matrix <- multmatrix[]
```

In the most recent version on the package [github](https://github.com/cdeterman/gpuR) version 1.2.2 has a convenience wrapper for `as.matrix`.  It will be available in the next release on CRAN.